# What game is played in the 2021 Virgin Media advert?

Tags: game-identification

The [advert](https://youtu.be/VDzu2DHtWac) (for Virgin Media) features two people playing an online game, who then have a video chat.

Here is a still from the advert showing them in the game:

[image: two online avatars, one in a wheelchair holding a giant gem]

I'm particularly interested in finding the name of the game as it allows your avatar in the game to use a wheelchair (I'm not looking for recommendations on other games however).

I'm fully aware the game may not exist outside of the advert, but as I am not in the loop I couldn't say for certain. As such, stating the negative would be an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It looks like this game is not a real production, but rather a <strike>demo</strike> animation developed exclusively for Virgin Media’s “Faster Brings us Closer” ad campaign.

You can read more about the marketing plan and agencies responsible for this commercial from [this article](https://www.virginmedia.com/corporate/media-centre/press-releases/happy-ever-avatar-virgin-medias-latest-campaign-features-an-in-game-love-story). No games or programmers are mentioned, only executives and visual effects artists.